# How to get tfs build associated changeset and workitem?

Tags: tfs, nant, tfsbuild

I want the value of tfs build associated changeset and work item for two reason -
1) Report/email confirmation through my custom proj file
2) Check out files which are related to changeset and work item

How can i do that? Any one can please give me a detail solution?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: I just wants a detail instruction or related links thats how i do that not step by step instructions ... thanks

Comment: What does that have to do with my comment? Have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: i get tfs build properties by the help of tfs GetBuildProperties Task .... but there is no idea about build associated changeset and work item. Then i found GenCheckinNotesUpdateWorkItems Task. But i didn't get build associated changeset and work item. I need those value to check out files which are related to changeset and work item. As i am new in this field , i haven't much knowledge about tfs.

Comment: Why are you using the tasks, in any case? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Start from the beginning: Tell us what kind of user does what kind of thing, _and then you want the changesets and work items_. For instance, "An administrator goes to a web page, chooses the build from a dropdown, _and then you want the changesets and work items_.

Comment: i have a nant script for build which i called from a .proj file (this .proj file is used in "Items to build" in tfs build definition) so that the whole build process works from the nant file. In that case, i use getbuildproperties task to get build related propertise for build and i have done that with my necessary properties except changeset and workitem. So i stack on that stage and searching a way to do that.

Comment: In the future, please _tell us_ things like this. Your question made little sense if you were using the latest version of TFS.

Comment: yes, i am using tfs 2012

Comment: And, which build process did you start with? The update process? In other words, why are you using MSBUILD tasks at all, and not workflow activities?

Comment: I am using the default build process and as i wrote to you that i have to use nant script(which is called from .proj file in build definition) as build process for some reason, i use msbuild task to get the desired values in .proj file and pass to nant. Another reason to use msbuild task is that i found as a solution. As i am new to tfs, i haven't prpper knowledge about workflow activities.

Comment: So, I take it that you're not the person who created this build process?

Comment: Yes, right. It was a huge build script that was wrote many years ago that i modified to use for tfs. I follow this way because that was recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "create report" permission, it is easy.
Try it, If you have problem, I help you.

Answer (score 0):

Get the msbuild community tasks and try this:

```
<MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Tfs.TfsVersion LocalPath="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Changeset" PropertyName="Changeset" />
</MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Tfs.TfsVersion>
```